# Static IP on Pi3 error

Tags: static-ip

I setup a static IP on my Pi using "/boot/cmdline.txt" (I run it headless most of the time)
But when i try booting it up with a monitor, mouse and keyboard it goes into the cli before booting(as usual) but then it shows:
 "waiting 110 seconds more for network"
 "waiting 100 seconds more for network"
 "waiting 90 seconds more for network"
...

To stop it i had to remove the ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in "boot/cmdline.txt"
But i want to set a static ip, How do i do it without getting the above error...

On further browsing i found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DCPDQnRXm8
please tell me if it is fine to do this

Pls help 
Thanks to anyone who tries to help me...

Comment: I assume you are running Raspbian. This runs `dhcpcd` by default. The old method of setting an IP in `cmdline.txt` may still work, but Raspbian is really designed to work out of the box with a normal network. Static IP addresses are a bad idea, but if you are determined to use one anyway see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Milliways: why do you say using static IP addresses is a bad idea? There are many use-cases for this: being able to connect reliably remotely, being able to assign it a DNS name etc.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo raspi-config`, disabling `Wait for Network at Boot`?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DCPDQnRXm8

This tutorial Works Great !!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.